# trying to use fread() on .csv file but getting internal error "ch>eof"

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I am getting an error from fread:

> Internal error: ch>eof when detecting eol

when trying to read a csv file downloaded from an https server, using R 3.2.0.   I found something related on Github, https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/src/fread.c, but don't know how I could use this, if at all.  Thanks for any help.

Added info:  the data was downloaded from here:

```
fileURL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06pid.csv"
```

then I used

```
download.file(fileURL, "Idaho2006.csv", method = "Internal")
```

Comment: can you show your code and possibly data to reproduce the error? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610 for providing a reproducible example.

Comment: please also show your code, especially how you call `fread` which seems to give you the error

Comment: mts, this time it worked correctly, so I think maybe the problem was how I was using fread (maybe because I stupidly didn't assign it to an object, eg DT <- fread("Idaho.csv").  Thanks for your patience with a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `download.file` doesn't work with https with `method=internal` unless you're on Windows and set an option.  Since `fread` uses `download.file` when you pass it a URL and not a local file, it'll fail.  You have to download the file manually then open it from a local file.

If you're on Linux or have either of the following already then do `method=wget` or `method=curl` instead

If you're on Windows and don't have either and don't want to download them then do `setInternet2(use = TRUE)` before your `download.file`

http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/setInternet2

For example:

```
fileURL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06pid.csv"
tempf <- tempfile()
download.file(fileURL, tempf, method = "curl")
DT <- fread(tempf)
unlink(tempf)
```

Or

```
fileURL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06pid.csv"
tempf <- tempfile()
setInternet2 = TRUE
download.file(fileURL, tempf)
DT <- fread(tempf)
unlink(tempf)
```

Answer (score 2):

`fread()` now utilises `curl` package for downloading files. And this seems to work just fine atm:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
fread(fileURL, showProgress = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this problem in my experience is to just remove the s from https. Also remove the method you don't need it. My OS is Windows and i have tried the following code and works.

```
fileURL <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Fss06pid.csv"
download.file(fileURL, "Idaho2006.csv")
```